# search in cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

in matlab I create an cell that contains arrays with different size. for example:

```
group{1} = [2;3;4];
group{2} = [4;5];
group{3} = [2;4;11;5;7];
```

I'm going to find element and delete them. if I search for '4' then the result should be as below:

```
group{1} = [2;3];
group{2} = [5];
group{3} = [2;11;5;7];
```

how can I do it in matlab? I tried find, ismember, [group{:}] .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use [`setdiff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html):

   ```
   remove = 4; %// may be a single value or a vector
   group = cellfun(@(x) setdiff(x,remove,'stable'), group, 'UniformOutput', 0);
   ```

   The `'stable'`option in `setdiff` is used for keeping original element order.
2. Alternatively, use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

   ```
   remove = 4; %// may be a single value or a vector
   group = cellfun(@(x) x(~ismember(x,remove)), group, 'UniformOutput', 0);
   ```
3. Possibly faster: if you only want to remove one value, simply use indexing:

   ```
   remove = 4; %// just one value
   group = cellfun(@(x) x(x~=remove), group, 'UniformOutput', 0);
   ```

Comment: it works wonderful. another question : how can I access to the index of groups that contain 'remove'. for this example {1} {2} {3} contains 4.

Comment: You need to slightly modify the `cellfun` statement. For example, in the second approach it would be `indices = find(cellfun(@(x) any(ismember(x,remove)), group))`